# I get The Error Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on integer

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

1. This is a normal code
2. TractorTable class
3. `UserReviews` class Following Code.

   ```
   public function getReviewAvgAndCount() {
       return $this->hasMany(UserReview::class, 'tractor_id');
   }

   function getAverageRatingAttribute() {
       return ($this->getReviewAvgAndCount()->count());
    }
   ```

   public function tractorTable()
    {

   ```
   return $this ->belongsTo('App\Model\TractorTable','tractor_id');
   ```

   }

Call Controller:

```
$obj=TractorTable::with('tractorImage','tractorSpecData','getAverageRatingAttribute','drive')->orderBy('tractor_id', 'desc')->take(5)->get();
```

Comment: how do you have the relationship from TractorTable to UserReviews setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't 'eager load' something that isn't a relationship. The `getAverageRatingAttribute` is an accessor, not a relationship method; it does not return a Relationship type object [BelongsTo, HasMany, etc].

Since you aren't eager loading the relationship that the accessor would be accessing, you are probably just trying to get a count of the relationship. Eloquent has the ability to do specifically this without loading the relationship completely and having to count the returned records. There is a `withCount` method for this purpose:

```
TractorTable::with('tractorImage', 'tractorSpecData', 'drive')
    ->withCount('getReviewAvgAndCount') // the relationship
    ->orderBy('tractor_id', 'desc')
    ->take(5)
    ->get();
```

Then you should be able to access that count via a property on each `TractorTable` instance (the relation name snake cased + '_count'):

```
$tractor->get_review_avg_and_count_count;
```

Assuming you are on Laravel >= 5.2.

[Laravel 6.x Docs - Eloquent - Relationships - Counting Related Models](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models) `withCount`

Comment: i want to display count with avg

Answer (score 0):

Eager loading (with) can be used only on relations: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

So `getAverageRatingAttribute` won't work.